# Replacing default images in Squarespace with JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, replace, attributes, squarespace

I am trying to replace the video icon on the site with a custom image. I thought I had the code right in the footer and using the attr feature, but I am not geting any results. What am I missing?

The icon is on the YouTube video links in teh "Movies" section on my client site at http://www.sunsetstudiosent.com

And my current code it:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".sqs-video-icon").attr("src", "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/50e3caa8e4b0c2f4977139be/t/5aad883e88251b563049bb78/1521322046538/play_icon.png");
    });
  </script>
```

It seems to be scourcing the url from a stock image on Squarespace, but I am not sure how to get this change to work.

[image code window for url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKI59.png)

```
.sqs-video-wrapper .sqs-video-overlay .sqs-video-icon {
    background-image: url('//static.squarespace.com/universal/images-v6/damask/play-button@2x.png');
    background-size: 33px;
}
.sqs-video-wrapper .sqs-video-overlay .sqs-video-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: transparent url('//static.squarespace.com/universal/images-v6/damask/play-button.png') center center no-repeat;
        background-image: url("//static.squarespace.com/universal/images-v6/damask/play-button.png");
        background-size: auto auto;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    margin-left: -24px;
    margin-top: -24px;
    cursor: pointer;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an "img" tag inside the "sqs-video-icon" div and use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".sqs-video-icon > img").attr("src", "https://static1.squarespace.com/static/50e3caa8e4b0c2f4977139be/t/5aad883e88251b563049bb78/1521322046538/play_icon.png");
});
```

Comment: That didn't change anything.